# How to access my server behind a router with public and private IP

Tags: networking, ftp

Thanks fellows, here's my question.

I have a FTP server running on my PC behind a router. Let's say its IP Address is 192.168.1.2

My public IP Address which is the IP I set in my Router is let's say it's 137.132.228.27

How I should I access my FTP server from Internet?

Normally people use port forwarding. Forward port 21(the FTP port) to my PC. But in my case the Router which is the property of university is out of my control so how can I access my FTP server with the two IP addresses given above.

Thanks

Linus

Comment: Maybe get a Dropbox account, or Copy.com and put your stuff that you want accessible on there... then you can access it from iPhone, iPad, Internet cafe, home, work.

Comment: Yeah, I know dropbox could do. I just want to try if this is possible

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can only run FTP server for(accessible from) local Computers. not the computers from the internet. Unless you forward ports to your pc(that you mentioned you can not so its not possible)

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, getting a Dropbox account is probably the simplest solution.

If you can't get your university IT admins to set up the port forwarding, then you may not be able to connect to it.